# Python function that changes variable parameters

Tags: python, function, global-variables

How can I rewrite my function so that when it runs, it changes the variables input as arguments? I have read you have to write `global` before each variable name but writing global before `a`, `b`, `c` parameters doesn't work and I can't figure out another way to make it work.

```
import sys

sys.stdin = open("/Users/isym444/Desktop/PythonCP/CP1/Codewars/Practice/input.txt", "r")
sys.stdout = open("/Users/isym444/Desktop/PythonCP/CP1/Codewars/Practice/output.txt", "w")

""" sys.stdin = open("mixmilk.in", "r")
sys.stdout = open("mixmilk.out", "w") """

c1, m1 = map(int, input().split())
c2, m2 = map(int, input().split())
c3, m3 = map(int, input().split())


def fun1(a, b, c):
    amt = min(a, b - c)
    a -= amt
    c += amt


# pours 1 to 99
for i in range(1, 34):
    fun1(m1, c2, m2)
    fun1(m2, c3, m3)
    fun1(m3, c1, m1)
# pour 100
fun1(m1, c2, m2)

result = [m1, m2, m3]
for i in result:
    print(i)
```

Note that this is a solution to USACO problem: 2018 December Contest, Bronze Problem 1. Mixing Milk -> http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=855

Comment: Don't do it that way, *return the value you need from your function*

Comment: I have tried like that and it still doesn't seem to be working. I tried running it via the debugger (with return(a,c) at the end of fun1) and m1,m2 stay the same when it passes the first line within the for loop for the first time

Comment: I realised now that I was forgetting to assign the return value to the old variables...Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
[...]
def fun1(a, b, c):
    amt = min(a, b - c)
    a -= amt
    c += amt
    return (a, b, c)

# pours 1 to 99
for i in range(1, 34):
    m1, c2, m2 = fun1(m1, c2, m2)
    m2, c3, m3 = fun1(m2, c3, m3)
    m3, c1, m1 = fun1(m3, c1, m1)
# pour 100
m1, c2, m2 = fun1(m1, c2, m2)
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I realised now that you assigned the m1,m2 to the return value of the function. Makes perfect sense now!